# Как задать css для класса если внутри блока 2 элемента

Tags: javascript

Как добавить новый класс для `<li class="li-child">` если внутри блока с классом `ul-parent` 2 `li`-элемента?

```html
<ul class="ul-parent">
   <li class="li-child">1</li>
   <li class="li-child">1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не понял в чем собственно вопрос? Обычно задаете: ul.ul-parent > li.li-child

Comment: @vantal отредактировал вопрос. Суть в том, что если внутри списка 2 li, не больше и не меньше, то мы добавляем им новый класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проходим циклом по всем значениям и добавляем класс

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ul-parent .li-child').forEach(elem=>elem.classList.add('new-class'))
```

**UPD**

Если задача состоит в том, чтобы отмечать только те элелменты, которые в кол-ве 2, то можно воспользоваться следующей проверкой.

```
let liElems = document.querySelectorAll('.ul-parent .li-child')

if (liElems.length === 2){
    liElems.forEach(elem=>elem.classList.add('new-class'))
}
```

Comment: А как добавить условие, чтобы скрипт действовал, если внутри только 2 пункта `li`?

Answer (score 1):

можно и на css, в принципе)

```css
.li-child {
  color: yellow;
  /* default value */
}

.li-child:first-of-type {
  color: green;
  /* if ul'l list more than 2 */
}

.li-child:only-of-type {
  color: red;
  /* if li provided it's the only child of it's parent */
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-parent">
  <li class="li-child">1</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul-parent">
  <li class="li-child">1</li>
  <li class="li-child">2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul-parent">
  <li class="li-child">1</li>
  <li class="li-child">2</li>
  <li class="li-child">3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

если для первого попавшегося по значению - querySelector

если нужны все элементы с этим классом - queruSelectorAll